# Using MySQL CONCAT_WS in WHERE Clause along with another WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: php, mysql

I am using **CONCAT_WS** in a query, but I need to limit my search to one client using the second WHERE clause. When I add the two WHERE clauses together it ignores my second condition and shows the campaigns for all clients.

Example clients: "ACME" and "NORTHWIND" - I cannot let the ACME customer see NORTHWIND's data and vice versa.

```
SELECT * FROM Campaigns WHERE CONCAT_WS (' ',id,created,campaign,client) 
AND client = '$client' LIKE '%$search%'
```

How do I make these WHERE clauses work together?

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are absolutely illogical.

While adding parenthesis according to the [Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html) we see that your code is:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Campaigns 
WHERE (CONCAT_WS(' ',id,created,campaign,client) AND ((client = '$client') LIKE '%$search%'))
```

I.e. in the conditions you

1. Compare `client = '$client'` obtaining some `X` (0, 1 or NULL)
2. Test `X LIKE '%$search%'` obtaining some `Y` (0, 1 or NULL)
3. Perform `CONCAT_WS(' ',id,created,campaign,client) AND Y` getting quite something unclear `Z`
4. Test does this `Z` can be treated as TRUE.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now.  I have rearranged to:  


`SELECT * FROM Campaigns WHERE client = '$client' AND (CONCAT_WS (' ',id,created,campaign) LIKE '%$search%')`  


That's what you get for coding at 3 am.  Thanks.